# using signal handler for ctrl-c - need help on infinite loops

Tags: c, linux, signals, signal-handling

I am using signal handler for ctrl-c signal. i.e whenever ctrl-c signal is generated instead of exiting the application I do some action.

Let us suppose if my application hangs due to while(1) loop (any error condition) is it possible for me to exit application only in that case?

ex:

```
void handle()
{
    /*do some action*/
    ----
    ----
    ---

    if ( while(1) detected)
    {
    exit(0);
    }
}


main()
{
    struct sigaction myhandle; 
    myhandle.sa_handler = handle;
    sigemptyset(&myhandle.sa_mask);
    myhandle.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &myhandle, NULL);

   while(1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) The declaration/definition/signature for your signal handler is wrong, it should be `void handle(int signum);` 2: lookup `man 2 siglongjmp`

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to find whether your code was in an accidental infinite loop before you received a signal like `Ctrl-C`. I can suggest some heuristic approaches. Have a variable of sufficiently long size, preferably a global `unsigned long long int`, and keep incrementing this variable inside the loops that you suspect might slip into infinite loops on every iteration of the loop. Now, when you receive a signal, check for the value of this variable in the signal handler against a threshold `MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS`. If the variable exceeds the user defined threshold then declare an infinite loop and `exit` else simply continue.

Something on these lines-

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 100000000

unsigned long long checkForEndlessLoop=0;
bool overflow;

void sigHandler (int signum)
{
   signal(sig, SIG_IGN); // Ignore it so that another Ctrl-C doesn't appear any soon
   if (overflow || (checkForEndlessLoop > MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS) )
   {
      //Something's fishy in the loop.
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      signal(SIGINT, sigHandler );
   }
}

int main ()
{
   signal(SIGINT, sigHandler );

   for (checkForEndlessLoop=0; SOME_SLOPPY_CONDITION; )
   {
      //Some processing here
      if (++checkForEndlessLoop == 0 )
          overflow=true;
   }

   checkForEndlessLoop=0;

   while (SOME_SLOPPY_CONDITION)
   {
      //Some processing here
      if (++checkForEndlessLoop == 0 )
          overflow=true;
   }

}
```

Or even simpler is, just ignore the `SIGINT` using `SIG_IGN` and `break` out of the faulty loop as soon as the faulty condition is detected, print out an error message and exit!

Comment: 2) siglongjmp 3) declare your condition variable as "volatile" to avoid the compiler to cache it's value.